# Trying to install FFmpeg via mac terminal and can't cd into the yasm folder

Tags: macos, terminal, cd, yasm

I couldn't expand the yasm archive via terminal so I did it via Finder, went back to terminal to cd into the folder and it says it doesn't exist even though I'm looking right at it in the Finder. What am I missing?

I took a screenshot but my reputation isn't high enough to post it. You can see it here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install yasm
brew install ffmpeg
```

If you don't have homebrew installed you can do it by typing the following:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was so much easier!